# Can not switch to nvidia graphics card because the kernel driver is not in use

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel, graphics

Good evening

I tried several times to switch to my nvidia graphics card on ubuntu 18.04.4. How ever it does not seem to work. After some research I found out that the kernel modules are available but the kernel drivers are not in use.

Here are some screenshots that may be useful

[lspci -knn | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8klJ.png)

[glxinfo | grep OpenGL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvN9F.png)

Comment: You're not logging in with Wayland are you (some choice under the gear icon on the login screen)?  For 18.04 that will switch video to the Intel driver even if the nvidia driver is installed.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is resolved. I had to enroll the MOK (machine owner key) after having installed the nvidia drivers (normally when installing the nvidia driver a MOK is asked) and after rebooting.

For this before logging in 
1.) Use ctrl+alt+f2
2.) use the following command
sudo update-secureboot-policy --enroll-key